# Android Studio - nested flavors (Gradle)

Tags: android, gradle

I am trying to generate different APKs for free and paid version (removed ads in layout files), additionally I want to track with Google Analytics downloads from different stores (Google Play, Amazon, etc.)

In the directory tree it would look like this:

```
\
\[free]
       \[amazon]
       \[googleplay]
       \common part for free app
\[pro]
      \[amazon]
      \[googleplay]
      \common part for paid app
```

Is it possible to have such build variants with Gradle build? If not, what would you be your suggested solution. I know I can prepare flavors in flat structure (amazonfree, amazonpro, googleplayfree, googleplaypro), but some of the code would have to be duplicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

flavorDimensions is what you search for. One dimension would be price for you ( free/paid ) and the other dimension is the store (play/amazon/..)

Comment: Perfect! This is even better solution than I expected. Thanks a lot for your answer.